# CSS: Table TD margin in IE

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a problem with a table in IE.
This is how it looks in Chrome (as its supposed to):

[image: Chrome view of the table]

This is how IE shows it:
[image: IE view of the table]

**MY HTML:**

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="15" class="content" align="center">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="293">
                <a href="/hvad-laerer-jeg.aspx"><img src="/UserFiles/image/hvadkanjeg.png" width="293" height="170" alt="" /></a><br />
                <br />
                <h1 style="margin-left: 40px;">Headline</h1>
                <p style="margin-left: 40px;">Text
            </td>
            <td width="292" style="margin:0 23px 0 23px;">
                <a href="/faglig-og-personlig-udvikling.aspx"><img src="/UserFiles/image/hjerne.png" width="293" height="170" alt="" /></a>
                <h1 style="margin-left: 40px;"><br />Headline</h1>
                <p style="margin-left: 40px;">Text
            </td>
            <td width="292">
                <a href="/ansoegning.aspx"><img src="/UserFiles/image/send.png" width="293" height="170" alt="" /></a>
                <h1 style="margin-left: 40px;"><br />Headline</h1>
                <p style="margin-left: 40px;">Text
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**The only CSS I have applied which is not inline is:**

```
table.content tr td { background:#ededed; margin-right:10px; }
    table.content tr td h1 { font-size:19px !important; }
```

**What I wish for and what I've tried:**
IE to display the table data as Chrome does with the margin and the alignment.
I have tried to use a "IF IE" and add padding - but it didn't help.
I also tried applying `Border-collapse:separate` and `border-spacing` but without success.

Any suggestions is appreciated!

Comment: Why are you telling your middle td to display block? Why are you assigning it special margins? Have you thought about/tried putting blank <td>s between these 3 and adding some CSS like `table.content tr > td:nth-of-type(even){background: transparent; width: 23px;}`?

Comment: Are you sure this is the entire code that affects on the table because I ran it on IE 5.5,6,7,8 and everything is like your Chrome image?  Perfectly the same in all browsers. Which version of IE you try ?

Comment: From http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html: Internal table elements generate rectangular boxes with content and borders. Cells have padding as well. Internal table elements do not have margins.

Comment: I'm using IE 9 - Ah I forgot to clean up the code before posting it. I tried all sorts of weird things to see what would happen (hence, I tried displaying it like a block). I havent used an empty TD in between because it also affects how it's viewed in Chrome.

Comment: You shouldn't be using tables for styling - tables are for tabular data

Comment: I have added your code to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5D2B/1/) and it looks like your IE example in all browsers.

Comment: It's being made in an editor, so using divs can be bad if the person editing it's content removes a div. Tables are just, easier to handle. Especially if the person editing the content dont know anything about inserting divs. Can you guys recommend an alternative solution to it's setup?